# Generation of jaxb groovy classes from xsd

Tags: groovy, jaxb

We have generated jaxb java classes from xsd for our java project.Now can we generate jaxb groovy classes for our new groovy project using xsd? If yes how to generate them?

Answer (score 0):

XJC compiler doesn't support Groovy. What's wrong with just Java files? Just keep them separate in your project and everything should be fine. It's ok to mix Java and Groovy in one projects:

```
src
  main
    groovy    <<< your Groovy code
    resources
  generated
    java      <<< XJC generated classes go here
```